# How to find out the character-encoding standard that has been used in a PHP file?

Tags: php, string, character-encoding, byte, string-literals

I'm using **PHP 7.2.11** on my laptop that runs on **Windows 10 Home Single Language 64-bit operating system**.

I've installed **Apache/2.4.35 (Win32) and PHP 7.2.10** using the latest version of **XAMPP**.

I typed in a below code into a file titled **demo.php** :

```
<?php
  $string1 = "Hel\xE1lo";  //Tried hexadecimal equivalent code-point from ISO-8859-1 
  echo $string1; 
?>
```

After running above program into my web browser it gave me below output :

```
Hel�lo
```

Then, I made a small change to the above program and re-wrote the code as below :

```
<?php
    $string1 = "Hel\xC3\xA1lo";  //Tried hexadecimal equivalent code-point from UTF-8, C form 
    echo $string1;
?>
```

After running the same program after making some change into my web browser it gave me below output **(Indeed the expected result)** :

```
Helálo
```

So, a doubt came to my mind after watching this stuff.

I want to know whether there is any built-in function or some mechanism in PHP which will tell me which character-encoding standard has been used in the current file?

**P.S. :** *I know that in PHP the string will be encoded in whatever fashion it is encoded in the script file. I want to know whether there exist some built-in function, some mechanism or any other way around which will tell me the character-encoding standard used in the file under consideration.*

Comment: Most charset detection only looks at the literal bytse/char encoding, but ignores C string / hex escapes.

Comment: PD of [Detect charset of string in PHP (UTF-8 or Windows-1256)](//stackoverflow.com/q/15188509) or [How to check the charset of string?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1037363)

Comment: @mario : Links of both the questions you given to me doesn't answer my doubt. I simply want a built-in function, some mechanism or some other way around which will give me the character-encoding standard used in the PHP file under consideration. That's it. Nothing more, nothing less. Even if the said PHP file is empty I should be able to get the character-encoding that will be used or set in that file with the help of some built-in function, some mechanism or some other way around. Thank You.

Comment: The better question is , assume such a built-in does not exist : in what way does it matter ?  cant you force the file encoding be a known encoding with your IDE and assume that ?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg : Actually, this question has been asked to me in a PHP technical interview today itself and I got stunned after hearing it. I never expected that I will get such kind of question in any interview. So, you must know very well that in an interview, it's not valid to assume anything or suppose anything. Interviewers always expect the firm, definite and confidently given answers from the interviewee. So, I'm seeking for some good, reliable answer for my question. I hope I will get the one from someone from our PHP community.

Comment: A: buy a good IDE if you want my services.  ps : there is over 20K open positions in PQ at the moment.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg : Currently, I use Sublime Text Version 3.1.1, Build 3176 which is pretty good for me as well as for other PHP Developers around the world. By the way, what does it mean by 'PQ' ?

Comment: La belle province du Québec :

Comment: @YvesLeBorg : See, I'm not able to understand what you are trying to say. I can understand English only. Please try to explain it in English language.

Comment: funny, your code snippet has french stuff ... made assumption. Province of Quebec, Canada.

Answer (score 0):

This function must be in the same file whose encoding is to be determined.

```
//return 'UTF-8', 'iso-8859-1',.. or false
function getPageCoding(){
  $codes = array(
    'UTF-8' => "\xc3\xa4",
    'iso-8859-1' => "\xe4",
    'cp850' => "\x84",
  );
  return array_search('ä',$codes);
}

echo getPageCoding();
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/UVvBM